# How ofter do I need to update my geoip lookup tables?

Tags: ip, geoip

I am considering using geoip for a web application.

However, **I am not sure how often "IP to city" information changes** and therefore **how often I need to update my geoip lookup tables**.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where you are getting your information from. Maxmind GeoLite updates their database once a month: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/